# How do you save data to database using EXT: Form in TYPO3 8.7.1?

Tags: forms, typo3, typo3-extensions

I need to create a contact form to allow users to send emails. Data must be saved in the database and notification send to the user. So far, I've been using EXT: Powermail, which works fine. In current project I'm using TYPO3 8.7.1 and I'd like to use EXT: Form 8.7.0. I've a test installation based on Introduction Package. I'm using predefined "Contact Form", but in the edition mode, I can't select finisher "Save to database". The only finishers I can see are: email to sender, redirect to a page, delete uploads.

- how to enable finisher to save form data into database? and where to select "Storage Id"?
- is it possible to list all records (emails) in List module similar as it is in Powermail extension?

I've been searching for some tips in a documentation, but couldn't find that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a SaveToDatabase-Finisher in the new Form Framework, but as far as I know you can only use it programmatically via YAML or API.

Here is the link to the corresponding doc: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/drafts/code.tritum.de/TYPO3.CMS/Form_Documentation/ApiReference/Index.html#savetodatabase-finisher